# Changing order of plist items with moveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I have a uitableview which is loaded with the contents of a plist. The plist contains the paths to images that are stored in the documents directory on the device. So when i use the moveRowAtIndex to change the order of the items in the tableview i dont know how to change the order of the items in the plist. [HERE is a link to what the plist looks like](http://gyazo.com/b1220ce15308b1a685af678a019c77f5)

So say if i had three images "Item 0", "Item 1" and "Item 2", and i swapped row 0 with row 3, how would i get it to change in the plist?

Also to clarify the table loads the files from the plist from top to botton it has nothing to do with the item numbers.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the array, you can get the object at the index of your "from row", remove that object from the array, and then insert it back at the index of the "to row". Here is an example (arr is the mutable array holding your table data):

```
    int toRow = 0;
    int fromRow = 3;
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:fromRow inSection:0] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:toRow inSection:0]];
    id obj = arr[fromRow];
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:fromRow];
    [arr insertObject:obj atIndex:toRow];
```